# Sort nested array using another array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, database, sorting

I got this array, comes from database. The order of values is changeable by the users

```
Array
 (
   [0] => 14
   [1] => 15
   [2] => 9
   [3] => 13
   [4] => 12
   ...
   [n] => n
 )
```

There is another array, which will be extracted to browser:

```
  Array
  (
   [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        ...
        [nr] => 9
        ...
    )
   [1] => Array
   (
        [id] => 2
        ...
        [nr] => 12
        ...
    )
    [2] => Array
   (
        [id] => 3
        ...
        [nr] => 15
        ...
    )
    [n] => Array
  )
```

I need to find a way to sort the this second array by `nr` (not `id`) and the `nr` order comes from the first array.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flip the first array in order to know what's the order of the id's:

```
$order = array_flip($order);
```

Then you simply use [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.usort.php) to sort the array based on the earlier flipped array:

```
usort($array, static function(array $a, array $b) use ($order) {
    return $order[$a['nr']] <=> $order[$b['nr']];
});
```

Comment: oh you are good! I have to study this one carefully! Thanks! I'll mark your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can just map your values to keys, and use that map to re-order.

```
<?php

$order = 
[
    2,
    5,
    1
];

$items =
[
    ['o' => 1],
    ['o' => 5],
    ['o' => 2],
];

foreach($items as $k => $v) {
    $map[$v['o']] = $k;
}

var_export($map);

foreach($order as $o) {
    $k = $map[$o];
    $result[$k] = $items[$k];
}

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
    1 => 0,
    5 => 1,
    2 => 2,
  )array (
    2 => 
    array (
      'o' => 2,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'o' => 5,
    ),
    0 => 
    array (
      'o' => 1,
    ),
  )
```

Assuming there's a one-one mapping.